# Is it possible to denote a domain is a copy of another domain?

Tags: seo, domains

Lets say I own two domains that point to the same content.

```
  foobar.com
a.foobar.com
b.foobar.com
  barfoo.com
```

`a.` and `b.` and testing servers, `barfoo.com` is a second domain that allows censored users to access the website.

I would like no hostname other than `foobar.com` to appear in Google searches. Is there a way of marking the other sites as copies?

Comment: We get this question a lot. Use canonical tags (at least). https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Look for the heading *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element* for an example. There is also other good information on this page.

Comment: Can you submit that as an answer so I can mark it correct? This is precisely what information I want.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful! We are here for you whenever you need us. We have some real experts here. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get this question a lot.

Use canonical tags (at least). A canonical tag simply points to the original page. It allows Google to know which page is to be indexed.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Look for the heading *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element* for an example.

There is also other good information on this page. It is a good one to bookmark for the future.